# AngularJS show the message provided by module

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing a MEAN stack application for educational purpose and I faced a problem while try to deal with angular modules and controllers.

Here is my modules.js code

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
    $routeProvider
        .when("/test1", {
            templateUrl : "views/test1.html",
            controller: "TestController",
            message: "Test 1"
        })
        .when("/test2", {
            templateUrl : "views/test2.html",
            controller: "TestController",
            message: "Test 2"
        });
});
```

Here is my test.controller.js code

```
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   // some code
}]);
```

And I have test1.html and test2.html files with this code segment.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <span>{{ message }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to show the messages "Test 1" and "Test 2" which are defined in modules.js file, in test1.html and test2.html respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a reference to $state object in your controller :

```
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
   $scope.myState = $state;
}]);
```

And in your view put this `{{myState.current.message}}`

You can take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/44ZuMZbLZCGfPgDS6L7X?p=preview)

**EDIT :**

In fact this probably works only if you use `ui-router` and you don't seems to use it.

**EDIT 2** :

So if you want to do this with `ngRoute` you need to get a reference to `$route` in your controller :

```
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $state) {
   $scope.myRoute = $route;
}]);
```

And to bind it in your view with :

```
{{myRoute.routes["test1"].message}}
```